# Grails: exception on uploading xml file

Tags: grails, file-upload

I tried to get and parse an XML file sent an upload from the GSP view.
The file is correctly sent by the client but when I tried to parse it I have an exception.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryPTpPKdL3WQWaPzJp--
 *(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect). Stacktrace follows:
Message: ------WebKitFormBoundaryPTpPKdL3WQWaPzJp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile.xml"*
```

**gsp:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="uploadXml">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**controller:**

```
def project = new XmlParser().parse(request.reader.text)
```

---

On using `request.getFile('file')`:

```
MultipartFile file = request.getFile('file')
```

I have another exception:

```
*| Error 2015-03-30 09:46:41,328 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [POST] /BOSWEBConfigurator/BOSOrder/uploadXml
No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [file]
Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getJSON(). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [file]
Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getJSON()*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlSlurpr (See this question [Slurpr vs Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558019/groovy-xmlslurper-vs-xmlparser))

In your controller

```
def uploadXml() {
    MultipartFile file = request.getFile('file')
    GPathResult xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file.inputStream)
}
```

And then you can process xml as you wish.

You can use [g:uploadForm](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Tags/uploadForm.html) tag to generate a multipart form if you like.

Make sure you dont have this config set to true grails.web.disable.multipart=true

Here's the spring security [issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-191) which you have encountered

Comment: I looked jira: I set grails.web.disable.multipart to false, then I added @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN']) at the top of the controller, but I still have the exception

Answer (score 0):

After invesigation, I noticed that I didn't added Spring Security statis rules in the **Config.groovy**:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
'myController/uploadXml' :['ROLE_ADMIN'']
]
```

Now its work